# LXDE - what command is isued when "eject" icon is pressed to umount FS

Tags: filesystems, ipod, eject, lxde, umount

Hello I have Fedora 16 with LXDE and I want to connect ipod shuffle 2nd gen 1GB. According to this page [ipod shuffle led blinking codes](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1407/HT1407_1.jpg) when amber LED is blinking this means that device is accessing by some proces or it is syncing data. The following I have observed:

1. When I connect ipod, the device it is automatically mounted and amber LED
   is blinking. So what I did is that I have used fuser and lsof (also
   on /dev) to find which process is accessing device, but I have found
   nothing and device was still amber blinking.
2. Then I tried to umount the automatically mounted device to figure
       out if LED will be shining, but nothing changed it was always
       blinking even FS was umounted.
3. So my third attempt was to use the "eject" button which is part of
       FileManager PCManFM contained in LXDE and is shown on mounted file
       systems. This helped! amber blinking stops and start amber shining,
       after few minutes the ipod was charged so the LED was green shining.

My question therefore is: What does the "eject" button does differently than classic umount command?

Answer (score 0):

The eject button probably uses the same kind of calls as the [eject command](http://eject.sourceforge.net/manpage.html), which uses ioctls to eject the device (the source code, with the various ioctls per device is [here](http://eject.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eject/eject/eject/eject.c?view=markup)).